# Keep hide javascript after refresh page

Tags: javascript, php

how to keep hide onclick 
this my javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function gethide(a){
    $("#brow"+a).hide();
    $("#del"+a).hide();
}
</script>
```

Comment: If english is not your first language, can I suggest you write the question in your language and then use a translateo like Google Translate to convert it to English. Currently it is not clear what you are asking us

Comment: You could store the state in local storage, which you then read on page load and hide it, if needed

Comment: do you mean hide after `onclick` ?  maybe you can show us your HTML (I guess there is `onclick="gethide(a)"`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With JQuery you need to do it after the DOM is ready.

This code will hide all elements with the `id` attribute that starts with `brow` or `del` after the page is loaded:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function gethide(a){
    $("#brow"+a).hide();
    $("#del"+a).hide();
}
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("[id^=brow]").hide();
    $("[id^=del]").hide();
});
</script>
```

See more in the [official documentation](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).

Comment: I'm guessing (not sure though) but it sounds like they want it to be hidden when a user clicks on something and are asking how to keep the state after page reload.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson ah, if you're true it's so more complicated :)